# Measurement of Bootstrap Grid System

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This few days I am trying figure out the calculate about Bootstrap Grid System.

According to the demo from Bootstrap website.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Example I am using a grid system on:-
**Desktop**: col-lg-12
**Tablet** : col-sm-6
**Mobile** : col-xs-12

How they measure desktop lg-12 = tablet sm-6 = mobile xs-12?

Why we can't just use lg-12 = sm-12 = xs-12?

Let me know if my question not clear enough.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks for explaining.

Comment: if you want a same size for all screen sizes, you can go with xs. col screensizes are states on the bootstrap webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences between the lg, sm, xs columns is only evident when you change the size of the window.  Try going back to http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ and play with the window size, you will see the divs appearance change as you make the window smaller and smaller. The way the divs change is based on whether they are lg, md, sm, or xs.